# Bound on constant in Polynomial so that zeros are bounded (Rouche)

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, upper-lower-bounds, rouches-theorem

Statement of the Problem: Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$ be a constant and consider the polynomial $$P(z)=z^{10}+a(z^9+z^8+z^7+z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1).$$ Given a radius $\rho>0$, use complex analysis to find an upper bound on $|a|$ of the form $|a|<\delta(\rho)$, $\delta(\rho)>0$, sufficient to guarantee that $P$ has all ten of its zeros in the disk $|z|<\rho$.

My work:  Consider $f(z)=z^{10}$ and $g(z)=a\left(z^9+z^8+z^7+z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1\right)$. Then:
$$\begin{align} 
|g(z)|&= |a
\left(z^9+z^8+z^7+z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1\right)|\\ &\leq |a||z^9+z^8+z^7+z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1| \\
& \leq |a|\left(|z|^9+|z|^8+|z|^7+|z|^6+|z|^5+|z|^4+|z|^3+|z|^2+|z|+1\right)\end{align}$$
Now we consider the region $|z|=\rho$ where $\rho>1$
$$\begin{align}
&\leq |a|\left(\rho^9+\rho^8+\rho^7+\rho^6+\rho^5+\rho^4+\rho^3+\rho^2+\rho+1\right) \\
&\leq |a|(10\rho^{10})
 \end{align}$$
Here we choose $|a| \leq \frac{1}{10}$
$$\begin{align}
&\leq 10|a|\rho^{10} \leq \rho^{10} =  |f(z)| \end{align}$$
$$|g(z)|\leq|f(z)|$$
Thus $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros by Rouché in $|z|\leq\rho$.

Do I need to show work for the case where $0<\rho<1$? or is this sufficient to answer the question? Am I understanding the question and demonstrating knowledge of the subject in my answer? (PS, I am studying for qualifying exams so any commentary on clarifying my proof or making it simpler, or even a better, simpler solution would be much appreciated) thankyou

EDIT: Work for case where $0<\rho<1$:
Say $0<\rho,1$, and $|z|<\rho$ then 
$$ \begin{align}|h(z)|& =|a\left(z^9+z^8+z^7+z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1 \right)|
\\ & \leq |a|\left(|z|^9+|z|^8+|z|^7+|z|^6+|z|^5+|z|^4+|z|^3+|z|^2+|z|+1 \right)\\
& \leq |a| \left(
 \rho^9+\rho^8+\rho^7+\rho^6+\rho^5+\rho^4+\rho^3+\rho^2+\rho+1 \right) \\
& \leq |a| (10)
\end{align}$$
Take $a\leq \frac{\rho^{10}}{10}$
$$ \leq \rho^{10} = |f(z)| \text{ for } |z|=\rho$$
Therefore we have shown that for the $0<\rho<1$ case, if we choose $a \leq \frac{\rho^{10}}{10}$ then $$|g(z)| \leq |f(z)|$$

Putting both cases together we have that for $a\leq\min\{\frac{1}{10},\frac{\rho^{10}}{10}\}$, $|g(z)|\leq|f(z)|$.

Thus $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros (10) in $|z|\leq\rho$

Edit from comment by user reuns

Note that $z^9+z^8+z^7+z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1=\frac{z^{10}-1}{z-1}$.

Using $g(z)=z^{10}$ and $f(z)=z^{10}+a\frac{z^{10}-1}{z-1}$

Then for $a<0$ we have that $|f(z)|<|g(z)|$ all z

Comment: Why do you have $\rho^{10}$ instead of $\rho^9$ in the bound of $\lvert g(z)\rvert$?  Yes you should also do $\rho\leq 1$.

Comment: @user10354138 I know $\rho>1$ so any power  $n<10$  of $\rho$ will be less than $\rho^{10}$ and i wanted to make my $g(z)$ less than $f(z)$ which has a power of 10

Comment: In the bound of $\rho^9+\rho^8+\dots+1\leq 10\rho^{10}$.  Just curious (yes, $\rho^{10}$ would also work, but $\rho^9$ is a more obvious choice).

Comment: @user10354138, i wanted to relate it to f(z) easily

Comment: Yes sorry. Let $f(z) = z^{10}+a \frac{z^{10}-1}{z-1}, g(z) = z^{10}$ then $h(z) =\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = 1+ a\frac{1-z^{-10}}{z-1}$, for $|z| > 2 (|a|+1)$ then 
 $\log h(z)$ is analytic so that  $f,g$ have all their distinct zeros on $|z| < 2(|a|+1)$

Comment: @reuns interesting, what theorem/principle are you using to know that the quotient being analytic in a bounded region implies that the numerator and denominator have all their zeros in that bounded region?

Answer (score 1):

Using $z=ρw$, the normalized equation for $w$ is
$$
w^{10}+a(ρ^{-1}w^9+...+ρ^{-9}w+ρ^{-10})=0.
$$
The Lagrange bound for the size of the roots is
$$
R=\max(1,|a|(ρ^{-1}+...+ρ^{-9}+ρ^{-10})
$$
As we want $|z|\leρ$, we need $R\le 1$, thus 
$$
|a|\le \frac{1}{ρ^{-1}+...+ρ^{-9}+ρ^{-10}}=\frac{ρ^{10}}{1+ρ+..+ρ^9}.
$$